# Getting different AES encrypted value when uploading a jar in Oracle database

Tags: java, encryption, oracle11g, aes

I am trying to do AES Encryption in Oracle database through Java.

Below is my java code

```
package com.test;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class AESTest {



  public static byte[] iv = {0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1};
  public static byte[] key = {0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1};

  public static String AES_Encrypt(String text) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    Cipher cipher;

    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

    byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    return encoder.encodeBuffer(results);

  }



  public static String AES_Decrypt(String text) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

    Cipher cipher;

    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    //byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(decoder.decodeBuffer(text));
    byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(decoder.decodeBuffer(text));
    System.out.println(bytesToHex(results));
    return new String(results, "UTF-8");

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException {

    System.out.println(AES_Encrypt("test_string"));
    System.out.println(AES_Decrypt("COIhB7Tc8AK5yUNufBBNgw==")); 
  }

}
```

Output:

```
COIhB7Tc8AK5yUNufBBNgw==
test_string
```

Now I created jar file of above code `AESTest.jar` and uploaded the same on Oracle database using below commands.

```
loadjava -u uname/pwd AESTest.jar
```

After that created 2 functions in `uname` schema

```
create or replace function AES_Encrypt(originalval varchar2) RETURN varchar
as language java
NAME 'com/test/AESTest.AES_Encrypt(java.lang.String) 
return java.lang.String';


create or replace function AES_Decrypt(originalval varchar2) RETURN varchar
as language java
NAME 'com/test/AESTest.AES_Decrypt(java.lang.String) 
return java.lang.String';
```

Now When I am trying to run below query

```
select AES_Encrypt('test_string') from dual;
```

Output is different : `COIhB7Tc8IO5yUNufBBNAA==`

**From java:** `COIhB7Tc8AK5yUNufBBNgw==`

**From DB:**   `COIhB7Tc8IO5yUNufBBNAA==`

Now, when I am, trying to decrypt (DB generated encrypted) value using DB function I am getting exception

`select AES_Decrypt('COIhB7Tc8IO5yUNufBBNAA==') from dual;`

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
29532. 00000 -  "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
*Cause:    A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be
           resolved by the Java code.
*Action:   Modify Java code, if this behavior is not intended.
```

However encrypted value generated by running Java code is getting decrypted successfully, even in the database.

`select AES_Decrypt('COIhB7Tc8AK5yUNufBBNgw==') from dual;`

Output : `test_string`

Not able to understand, what I am missing. Please suggest.

Oracle DB version - 11.2
JDK version - 1.5